# Android Retrofit get response before cursor next loop

Tags: android, android-sqlite, retrofit

```
@OnClick(R.id.btnCheckStockId) void callCheck() {

    MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(ScanBarcodeActivity.this);
    final SQLiteDatabase sql = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT barcode FROM stockopname where lokasi_item = ?";
    cursor = sql.rawQuery(query, new String[]{lokasiItem});

    try {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            final String stockId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("barcode"));
            //API RETROFIT
            ApiService api_check = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);

            Call<String> call = api_check.check_barcode(stockId);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                    //get result
                    String sync_result = response.body();
                    String set_sync = "";

                    if (sync_result == "true") {
                        set_sync = "true";
                    } else {
                        set_sync = "false";
                    }

                    //update data on sqlite
                    ContentValues updatecolumn = new ContentValues();
                    updatecolumn.put("is_sync", set_sync);
                    sql.update("stockopname", updatecolumn, "barcode = ?", new String[]{stockId});

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So the logic is, get a list from stock_id from the local database then check the server with API, if true the stock_id already exists on the server, if false the stock_id data does not yet exist. and the results of the responses need to be updated back to the local database with the column is_sync = true/false

when debugging, the pointer does not enter into onResponse but enters the next loop

I want to ask and need advice on how to get a response from the server immediately before the next loop in the cursor (using sqlite database), is there a solution?

Update, My Solution after reconstruct the code :

```
    @OnClick(R.id.btnCheckStockId) void callCheck() {

    MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(ScanBarcodeActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sql = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT barcode FROM stockopname where lokasi_item = ?";
    cursor_checksync = sql.rawQuery(query, new String[]{lokasiItem});

    if (cursor_checksync != null) {

        //more to the first row
        cursor_checksync.moveToFirst();

        //iterate over rows
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor_checksync.getCount(); i++) {

            callCheckSync(cursor_checksync);

            cursor_checksync.moveToNext();
        }
        //close the cursor
        cursor.close();
    }

}


public void callCheckSync(Cursor csr_checksync)
{

        final String stockId = csr_checksync.getString(csr_checksync.getColumnIndex("barcode"));
        //API RETROFIT
        ApiService api_check = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);

        Call<String> call = api_check.check_barcode(stockId);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                //get result

                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String sync_result = response.body();
                    String set_sync = "";

                    if (sync_result == "true") {
                        set_sync = "true";
                    } else {
                        set_sync = "false";
                    }
                    //update data on sqlite
                    update(stockId, set_sync);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

    }


public void update(String Barcode, String value)
{
    MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(ScanBarcodeActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sql = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues updatecolumn = new ContentValues();
    updatecolumn.put("is_sync", value);
    sql.update("stockopname", updatecolumn, "barcode = ?", new String[]{Barcode});
}
```

I don't know if this is the best approach, but it solves my problem.

Comment: don't use `while` loop but `Cursor`'s `moveNext()` to iterate in recursive way.

Comment: @adnbsr can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this method on onClick after defining initial cursor. Sorry for syntax I dont have IDE.

```
    public void callMethod(Cursor cursor){

        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            //Retrofit
            onResponse: () -> {
                callMethod(cursor);
            }
        }else {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer, you give me a hint!. i try to reconstruct the code and now my problem has solved.  thank you very much.